# Display an image in place of a check mark with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox, background-image, imagebutton, checkboxlist

I found this code on here. Does anyone know if this would work with codeigniter. I want the ability for some to click on a image and perform the same function as a check box. After you click the image it would display a new image overlay that would be a check mark on top of the image.

Code I found.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><path id="checkbox-3-icon" fill="#000" d="M81,81v350h350V81H81z M227.383,345.013l-81.476-81.498l34.69-34.697l46.783,46.794l108.007-108.005 l34.706,34.684L227.383,345.013z"/></svg>');
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"> <path id="checkbox-9-icon" d="M391,121v270H121V121H391z M431,81H81v350h350V81z"></path> </svg>');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: It's not related to codeigniter. It's a simple html checkbox, btw yes, it will work with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!